# Internet Explorer VBA automation working on all but 1 computer

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer-8

I've been struggling with a problem for a macro that uses IE to open up a webpage and download values from a table to Excel. 
The macro works fine on all but 1 of my colleagues computers here at work. I can't figure out why his computer behaves the way it does, as it should have all the same settings and installations as we have (I work at a larger company).

UPDATE: Whole code is included, but removed the URL as you need login/password to access the URL anyways.

For us other users the code works fine, the only thing we see while the macro is running is the progressbar. We can't see the IE-window open up and so on, since its done in the background.
But for the other user, a internet explorer window pops up at the "ie.navigate url" part, and the macro stops at either "IE.Busy" or "IE.Document" since it doesn't seem to know that IE is running..

We have the same versions of excel and internet explorer, windows etc.. Same references are checked in the VBA.. But somehow his Excel can recognize IE.Navigate but after that it can't control the IE-application..

Anyone had a similar problem or have any suggestions for what I can try?

Thanks.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Grupp_3()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim tbls, tbl, trs, tr, tds, td, r, c
    Dim countery2 As Long
    Dim ANTAL As Long
    Dim TID, radhopp, MGAKODER, TYPER, NAMN, countery, row, 
    MGAKOD, TYP 
    Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    On Error GoTo ErrMsg

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IMPORT").Select
    Range("A239:I306").ClearContents

    Radhopp = Range("O31").Value
    Set KODER = Range("Q31:Q34")
    countery = 1
    ANTAL = 4

    UpdateProgressBar 0, ANTAL

    For Each Row In KODER.Cells

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("IMPORT").Select

        IE.navigate "real URL here"

        ' Wait while IE loading...
        Do While IE.Busy
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", TID, Now)
        Loop

        Set tbls = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")

        For r = 0 To tbls.Length - 1
            Debug.Print r, tbls(r).Rows.Length
        Next r

        Set tbl = IE.Document.getElementById("TABLE_OVERVIEW")
        Set trs = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")

        For r = 0 To trs.Length - 1

            Set tds = trs(r).getElementsByTagName("td")
            'if no  then look for
            If tds.Length = 0 Then Set tds = trs(r).getElementsByTagName("th")

            For c = 0 To tds.Length - 1
                ActiveSheet.Cells(Radhopp, 1).Offset(r, c).Value = tds(c).innerText
            Next c
        Next r
countery2 = countery
UpdateProgressBar countery2, ANTAL


countery = countery + 1
Radhopp = Radhopp + 17
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Grupp 3").Select
Next Row

Range("N1").Value = Now
Application.StatusBar = ""

IE.Quit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Exit Sub
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Grupp 3").Select

ErrMsg:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
MsgBox ("Error, check that you're logged on in IE"), , "OK"
Application.StatusBar = ""
IE.Quit
ProgressBar.Hide
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Grupp 3").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is indeed an interesting question! Can you write `Option Explicit` on the top of your example and update the code in a way, that it compiles? Thanks! :)

Comment: If you want to see the `IE` when it is openning, consider writing `ie.visible = true` after the `Set IE = CreateObject...` line.

Comment: @Vityata I updated the code with option explicit and added some dim variables. Not exactly sure what you mean by compile in this case, but the code is more complete now, but another URL with a login that we're using.

Comment: @Vityata Putting ie.visible=true or false makes no difference for the user. It shouldn't be visible by default.. at least no other user can see it opening. IE is visible only for the user that can't run the code without error.

Comment: @JimmyEl Check IE [browser mode](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=ie+browser+mode), [document mode](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=ie+document+mode), [compatibility view](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=ie+compatibility+view). Finally try to reset IE settings to default.

Comment: Try Debug.print Ie.document.Getelementsbytagname(“”)(0) sorry read it wrong if no one answers this question I’ll update by reply when by my computer.

Comment: In the mean time look up how to use “Sleep” and “doevents”

Comment: @omegastripes , I tried checking browser mode, document mode and different compatibilities. Also tried resetting IE settings!  We'll now try reinstalling IE and Excel.

Comment: @JimmyEl Check security settings also, i. e. security zones, IIRC if you navigate to website located in another security zone, then IE will be restarted in a separate process, that makes`IE` variable reference to object lost.